# How to undo a transpose with zip?

Tags: python

I am working on a list containing of tuples like

```
list = [(1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7, 8), (9, 10, 11, 12)]
```

and transpose it

```
transpose = zip(*list)
```

so i get

```
transpose = [(1, 5, 9), (2, 6, 10), (3, 7, 11), (4, 8, 12)]
```

after that i am removing some of the tuples of the transponed list for example the second tuple `(2, 6, 10)`. How can i undo the transpose now? I want to achieve a list like:

```
[(1, 3, 4), (5, 7, 8), (9, 11, 12)]
```

Comment: You do realise that transposing is reversed by transposing?

Comment: Although I don't think this is your issue, don't overwrite python builtins/keywords such as `list` unless you really know what you're doing as now you won't be able to use the keyword `list` as originally intended by the language.

Comment: It's in the `zip` function's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip). Note the last example with the `zip(*zip(x, y))`.

Comment: Beside the point, but you might be accidentally using the wrong version of Python since you're saying `zip` gives you a list, but in Python 3, it should give you an iterator. I already removed the [tag:python-3.8] tag since this isn't specific to 3.8, and then I was going to add back the [tag:python-3] tag until I noticed the problem.

Comment: @Pavel what about keeping track the position of the removed tuple and add it again using a slice around that index? ... or you can avoid to remove... or make a copy of the original one... don't understand what is about the `zip`stuff and more generally what are you doing